# Principle of a pyrometer

Tags: temperature, laser, thermal-radiation, measurements

How does a [pyrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrometer) work? Especially how do I ensure that the temperature of a single spot is measured (where the laser points at)?

Here is a scheme of the structure but I guess it's not really needed here:
[image: Structure]

Comment: [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) from spot is focused into detector [{thermoelectric, pyroelectric, bolometer}](https://www.optris.com/tl_files/downloads/Presse/englisch/press-article-world-of-industries-infrared-cameras-and-pyrometer.pdf) which maps electric signal into temperature

Comment: There's no laser in the diagram in your question. The instrument in the diagram has a optical viewfinder instead of a laser sight.  Either way, how do you know that the spot designated by the sight is the same spot that is measured? If you can't trust that it was accurate when it came from the factory, or you can't trust that somebody hasn't done something to knock it out of alignment, then you'll have to test it yourself. Maybe arrange to place a small hot object against a cold background, stand back with your pyrometer, and see if it gives the result that you expect.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Is the laser only to point at the certain spot? Finally, I know this point is measured because of the lense?

Comment: The designers of your instrument knew the answers to your questions, and they should have put the information in documents that came with it. Do you still have the documentation? Can you get it on line? Does it answer your questions?  If not, then you may have to spend the money for a higher-quality, better documented (and maybe certified/calibrated) instrument.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I have no instrument and no document. The question is quite general and does not aim at any specific manufacturer or device. I just want to know how pyrometers work.